# Migrating withRouter from v5 to v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have been googling for what feels like forever and cannot come up with a solution to this issue. This app uses the following `withRouter` use case in a large number of it's class based components to make state available within those components.

```
class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    const {user} = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(state => ({
  user: state.user
}), {loadUserCurrent})(Home));
```

I have read the [FAQs](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/48b7c60a2133a617d64533b54eb299dbd2d1be0e/docs/faq.md#faqs) for react-router that shows an example of how to migrate but does that mean all the class based components that use withRouter need to be changed to functional components?

What can I use to replace withRouter in the final export?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` :

```
const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUserCurrent())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <Container>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Then, `useParams`, `useLocation`, and `useHistory` allow you to access the same information that you would get from the `withRouter` HOC

Comment: Thanks for the response. So essentially it's move to a functional component or use a custom withRouter?

Comment: Essentially, yes

Comment: @rick_grimes Yes. React function components and hooks are the future of React at the moment. React class components have been effectively deprecated but retain compatibility for now.

Comment: Yep ok that makes sense. In personal projects I have always used functional components but this work app is only class based and it is fairly large so will be a big job to migrate everything.